# How to count the results after filtering with HAVING?

Tags: sparql

Here is my query

```
SELECT ?s (COUNT (?p) as ?np) 
WHERE {
    ?s a ex:Class ;
      ?p ?o .

}
GROUP BY ?s
HAVING (?np < 8)
```

It gives the list of results that I want. How can I count them?

Comment: a sub-select? e.g. `select (count(*) as ?count) { select ?s .... having (?np < 8) } `